# Eclipse RCP : How to use Nebula NatTable feature?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nebula, nattable

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html) to have a NatTable in my e4 RCP applicaton product. My app is feature based not plug in based as shown in Tutorial. I followed and installed these features. When I try to launch the product, I encounter following error

Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core; bundle-version="1.3.0"

Can anybody share any sample about how to use nebula features successfully?

Comment: Have you included the Nattable features in your product file?

Comment: @greg-449 yes I have included that feature in my .product file as <feature id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core.feature" version="1.3.0.201503261201"/>

Comment: Is that all you get as a message?

Comment: Can you post the full log?

Comment: @AryeShemesh It got resolved, as some plug-ins were not added, which I did through Run_configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the tutorial you posted, NatTable Core has dependencies to the following plug-ins:

- org.eclipse.swt
- org.eclipse.jface
- org.eclipse.equinox.common
- org.eclipse.core.commands
- org.apache.commons.logging

In most cases org.apache.commons.logging is missing in the product configuration and needs to be added in another feature.

Comment: Thank you Dirk, I added "org.apache.commons.logging"

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem, by

run configurations --> Plug ins --> Add Required Plug-ins

Then it worked.